# Foundation 3 & Javascript Issue

Tags: javascript, expressionengine, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation 3 and have a dropdown set to change the url based on what is selected. 
 The code in curly braces is ExpressionEngine tags which are working correctly.
HTML - select is hidden - see foundation docs, bottom of page here, http://bit.ly/1b9gAjG:

```
<form id="materials-year" class="custom">
    <select  class="support attribute" style="display:none;" onChange="this.form.submit()">
      <option>Select Year</option>
      <option value="{site_url}members/">All</option>
      {exp:low_yearly_archives channel="member-materials" limit="50"}
      <option value="{site_url}members/{year}/">{year}</option>
      {/exp:low_yearly_archives}
    </select>

    <div class="custom dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="current">
        Select Year
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="selector"></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/members/">All</a></li>
        {exp:low_yearly_archives channel="member-materials" limit="50"}
        <li><a href="/members/{year}/">{year}</a></li>
        {/exp:low_yearly_archives}
      </ul>
    </div>
</form>
```

Form does not submit since there's no submit button. However adding the following javascript the form will submit correctly if I unhide the select, but that looks ugly.

javascript

```
// Year Drop Down on members page
// change url
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#materials-year select').change(function(){
        window.location = $(this).val();
    });
});
```

Can't figure out what to change to have the dropdown work without a submit button. All help is greatly appreciated.

**update**

Looks like Foundation is stripping out the a tags in the dropdown div.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.dropdown').on('click', 'li a', function (e) {
      var location = this.href;
      if (location != '') { // require a URL
            window.location = location; // redirect
        }
      e.preventDefault();
});

//also make sure the values in your select are actual full URLs
```

Comment: crap - let me know what you came up with. Strange, this really should work.

Comment: For the time being, due to time constraints and client pressure, I've gone with just a plain select field. Will revisit later and see if I can get it to work correctly.